# Sumifs with a list of criteria

Tags: excel

I would like to have a sumifs formula where it refers to a list of possible variables ie different account numbers.  I would prefer to do it rather than hard code it as individuals can

So effectively doing a sumifs for each of the account codes and adding them together in one cell.  I know I could effectively add them up but was wondering if there was a more flexible approach.  As new accounts may get added etc.

I could also do a total of each account separately and add the totals which would also work but would be more clunky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following array formula will work:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A8,D2:D6,B2:B8))
```

It is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.

And as @XOR LX just explained using sumproduct instead of sum makes it a non forced array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A2:A8,D2:D6,B2:B8))
```

I set up my sheet like this:

[image]

Comment: You could also replace SUM with SUMPRODUCT in which case no CSE is required.

Comment: If I have more than one criteria ie date and account number - will this work as its a sumif not a sumifs.  I remember back in the day before sumifs I used sumproduct but not for this example.  Thanks.

Comment: @LouisaThompson I only works as a one to one relationship, as in the date would need to be exact not a range. And each date would correspond to one name. For example you have multiple `scott`s but the dates are all different and you want 2 dates to count then `scott` would need to be in twice with both exact dates. If you want a range of account and a greater than less than on the dates you will need to use vba. Or as suggested you could use pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {=sumif(range_of_accounts, criteria, range_of_values)}
```

Comment: I have more than one criteria.  So will be date which will be fixed and accounts which will be variable.  I will have a play around.  Thanks.

Comment: Honestly what you want can be easily achieved via pivot tables. It'll be faster and easier than trying to do a plug and play formula.